# How can I optimize this Python code please?

Tags: python

I have a dataset from a bivariate normal, each datapoint however, is drawn from a different member of the family, ie the mean and the covariance matrix varies. I am trying to optimize my code and I am wondering if there is a better way to do it please.

At the moment, I am using a list comprehension and I have tried parallelism with no great success. For 100,000 datapoints the list comprehension finishes in around 8secs and parallelism takes about a couple of seconds longer.

The size of my data can be anywhere from a few hundred thousands to a couple of million, but the data are going to be always from the bivariate Gaussian. Also as I said each datapoint is drawn from a bivariate gaussian with different mean and covariance, but in the code snippet below I am taking the simplest possible case and I pass-in the same covariance and mean for all data.

Any ideas much appreciated!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
from timeit import timeit


def mvn_loglik(param):
    out = [multivariate_normal.logpdf(p[0], p[1], p[2]) for i, p in enumerate(param)]
    return out

def mvn_loglik_helper(p):
    out = multivariate_normal.logpdf(p[0], p[1], p[2])
    return out

def mvn_loglik_par(param):
    n = max(1, cpu_count() - 1)
    pool = ThreadPool(n)
    results = pool.map(mvn_loglik_helper, param)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return results

n = 100000
data = np.zeros([n,2])
mu = np.zeros([n,2])
cov = np.tile(np.eye(2,2), (n,1,1))

param = list(zip(*[data, mu, cov]))
assert np.all(mvn_loglik(param) == mvn_loglik_par(param))

def f():
    param = list(zip(*[data, mu, cov]))
    return mvn_loglik(param)

def g():
    param = list(zip(*[data, mu, cov]))
    return mvn_loglik_par(param)


print(timeit(f, number=1))
8.6705456

print(timeit(g, number=1))
10.187561600000002
```

Comment: I think this code has been optimized and in my opinion it couldn't be any more. You cannot optimize it with software but you can do this by upgrading the hardware (your PC). Or you can use google service (GoogleColab).

Comment: Why do you need to construct a list? Could you use the result of your algorithm element by element, using a `yield` construct. List construction and access is quite expensive, and the `yield` statement is an amazing and scary way to avoid doing that, by generating the implied calculated sequence on the fly, as needed.